# Cannot modify the return value of 'Control.Location' because it is not a variable

Tags: c#

Please keep in mind I just started c#.
I have this code:

```
                player.Location.Y += 8;
```

but sadly I get this error on player.Location

```
Cannot modify the return value of 'Control.Location' because it is not a variable
```

My full code is:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            player.Location.Y += 8;
            timer2.Interval = 600;
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }
```

My goal is:

Raise "player"s Y by 8 then start a timer that slowly drops him.

Comment: Something every .NET programmer has to learn once, Point is a value type.  So the Location property returns a *copy* of the value and your code updates the copy.  Which has no effect.  The hard way is reassigning the Location property with new Point(...), the trivial way is `player.Top += 8;`.

Comment: thanks @HansPassant, that worked :) and to all the people marking this as duplicate-  i wanted it to be specifically explained since i do not know c# very well